# How to calculate coordinates in TikZ without separating axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code below generates coordinate A at (cos 37°, sin 37°).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tikzmath{\x=37;} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at ($cos(\x)*(1,0)+sin(\x)*(0,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I change the line defining the coordinate to below, it no longer works.

```
\coordinate (A) at ($(cos(\x),sin(\x))$);
```

Separating axes could be a pain when there are many of them. How can I write everything in one coordinate?

Comment: To your last paragraph: How many "separating axes" do you have? You can also do `([x=(45:1cm), y=(-45:2cm)]37: 1)` to get `cos 37 * (45:1cm) + sin 37 * (-45:2cm)`. Maybe there's an easier way to specify the coordinates than with all of that math.

Answer (score 2):

You need to protect the `)` from the trigonometric functions otherwise the coordinate parser will do nasty things.

Meaning it will think `cos(\x` is a coordinate specification and since it doesn't fit any of the other valid TikZ coordinate specifications it will assume `cos(\x` to be the name of a coordinate or node:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named `cos(37' is known.
```

And then the `calc` library can't deal with `), sin(\x` anymore:

```
Package tikz Error: + or - expected.
```

---

In your case, this should be

```
\coordinate (A) at ($({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)})$);
```

or – in this simple case –

```
\coordinate (A) at ($(cos \x, sin \x)$);
```

Note that you don't need the `calc` library for this. TikZ throws every coordinate part in PGFmath anyway:

```
\coordinate (A) at (cos \x, sin \x);
% or
\coordinate (A) at ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});
```

PGF/TikZ also has polar coordinates built-in. You could have just used

```
\coordinate (A) at (\x : 1);
```

This can also deal with different radii:

```
\coordinate (A) at (\x : 1 and 2); % i.e. cos \x * (1, 0) + sin \x * (0, 2)
```